# PIN pad Issue with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need help with Selenium WebDriver. I was trying to automate a site but got stuck in the PIN pad area.

When I clicked on the PIN input element, the element is in read only and can only accept value via mouse clicking of the pin code. Note that the position of numbers on the PIN Pad changes whenever it popup/refresh.

EDIT (added information):

It's available publicly www.mypaga.com. You can use this ID to perform some transaction like AcceptDeposit. username: ibile, security question: 4, password: ibile4live

Here is the code:

```
package com.paga.testing.agent.online;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assume;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class AcceptDepositTest extends LoginTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beginTest() {
        System.out.println("********* Begin *************");
        Assume.assumeTrue(loginTest());
    }

    @Test
    public void acceptDepositTest(){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("acceptDeposit")));
        System.out.println("acceptDepositTest Running");
        driver.findElement(By.className("acceptDeposit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("amount")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("amount")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("amount")).sendKeys("1000");
        driver.findElement(By.id("customerPhoneNumber")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("customerPhoneNumber")).sendKeys("08022614279");
        driver.findElement(By.className("button_go")).click();
        System.out.println("pin pad");


     // Enter PIN
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("confirmPin")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("confirmPin")).click();
        System.out.println("pin pad22");
        driver.findElement(By.id("confirmPin")).sendKeys("1234");

        driver.findElement(By.className("button_go")).click();

        //driver.findElement(By.id("confirmPin")).sendKeys("1234");
        //return flag;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void ending(){
        System.out.println("********* End *************");
    }
}
```

And this is the PIN PAD Code. Please note that the position of the PIN pad value changes at every refresh

```
<div id="keypad-div" style="text-align: left; float: left; position: absolute; top: 431.067px; width: auto; left: 915.817px; display: block;">
    <div class="keypad-row">
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">9</button>
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">7</button>
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">2</button>
        <button class="keypad-key keypad-close" title="Close the keypad" type="button">Ok</button>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad-row">
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">4</button>
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">3</button>
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">6</button>
        <button class="keypad-key keypad-back" title="Erase the previous character" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad-row">
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">5</button>
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">1</button>
        <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">8</button>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad-row">
    <div class="keypad-space"/>
    <button class="keypad-key" title="" type="button">0</button>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't. We haven't seen your code, nor the code of the site. Is it a publicly available site? Please, let us see what you have done so far. Share your code, let us see at least the HTML structure of the PIN pad.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Here is the Below:

Comment: I have Added the code above, hope you figure out the state of the PIN PAD

Answer (score 0):

For that particular PIN pad, can you send the PIN number since you already know the element ID?  Similar to the following example:

/* Submit PIN Number */

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("pin_id")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("pin_id")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("pin_id")).sendKeys(pinID);
```

Comment: I did exactly the same in my code but still not working